# on change event listening for limits to checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, input, onchange

I have created a select input where you choose from three limit options (5, 3 or 2). I then have 5 possible inputs below. The options below, which are holidays are checkbox inputs. The limit code I have disables a selection being made after the limit is reached, ie: if 3 is selected, you will not be able to exceed 3 selections.

*My primary issue is that it seems the change function is not effecting the limit count. So, if you select 3 from the limit select input and then choose three choices, then decide you want to increase the limit and you choose the select input from 3 to 5, it does not allow the user to choose two additional options.

*Then if you choose 3 from the select input, once you select three options, if you unselect a checkbox, it will not allow you to choose a different option. It only allows you to choose the same option you clicked off of.

Just so you know, when an option is selected, the alt image will appear. To be able to click options, the select input needs to be selected first.

Does anyone know why these issues are present?

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/fv6ckupu/)

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function(bool) {
  return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
}
  $('#tp-frequency').on('change', function() {
    var templates = $('#tp-frequency option:selected').val();
    $('#template-number').html(templates);

    // Setting limit for templates
    $('.tp-template-check').on('change', function() {
      var limitTemplate = templates;
      if (!this.checked || $('.tp-template-check:checked').length <= limitTemplate) {
        $(this).parents('.product-wrap:first').find('.checkmark-img').fadeBoolToggle(this.checked);
        var templateCount = $('.tp-template-check:checked').length;

        if (templateCount > 0) {
          $('#templateCount').html(templateCount + " Template" + (templateCount == 1 ? "" : "s") + " Selected");
        }
        if (templateCount >= limitTemplate) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('.tp-template-check[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
          alert("You reached your limit");
        }
        if (templateCount == limitTemplate) {
          $('#templateCountComplete').fadeBoolToggle($('.tp-template-check:checked').length == limitTemplate).addClass('block');
        } else if (templateCount > limitTemplate) {
          $('.tp-template:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
          $('#templateCountComplete').hide();
          $('#test2').toggle().html('It worked');
        }
      } else {
        $('#templateCountComplete').hide();
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.product-check, .tp-template-check, #templateCountComplete, .checkmark-img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="section-subtitle">Choose the limit</h2>
<select id="tp-frequency" class="option-input">
  <option value='' disabled selected>Please choose option</option>
  <option value='5'>5</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
<div id="tp-template-section">
  <!-- Template Section -->
  <h2 class="section-subtitle">Choose <span id="template-number"></span> templates from below.</h2>
  <p id="test2"></p>
  <p id="templateCount"></p>
  <div id="templateCountComplete">Templates Reached Limit</div>
  <div id="tp-template-wrap">
    <div class="tp-template">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="tp-winter" class="package-check-toggle">
          <h4 class="tp-template-title">Winter</h4>
          <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Winter" data-template-image="<img src='images/tp-winter.png' class='review-img'>" id="tp-winter" value="Winter">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tp-template">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="tp-spring" class="package-check-toggle">
          <h4 class="tp-template-title">Spring</h4>
          <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Spring" data-template-image="<img src='images/tp-spring.png' class='review-img'>" id="tp-spring" value="Spring">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tp-template">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="tp-summer" class="package-check-toggle">
          <h4 class="tp-template-title">Summer</h4>
          <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Summer" data-template-image="<img src='images/tp-summer.png' class='review-img'>" id="tp-summer" value="Summer">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tp-template">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="tp-fall" class="package-check-toggle">
          <h4 class="tp-template-title">Fall</h4>
          <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Fall" data-template-image="<img src='images/tp-fall.png' class='review-img'>" id="tp-fall" value="Fall">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tp-template">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="tp-newYears" class="package-check-toggle">
          <h4 class="tp-template-title">New Years</h4>
          <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="New Years" data-template-image="<img src='images/tp-newYears.png' class='review-img'>" id="tp-newYears" value="New Years">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```